# Solid hydrophilic transparant materials that don't dissolve in water

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, polymers, surface-chemistry

I am looking for hydrophilic transparant materials which are solid at room temperature and that don't dissolve in water. I need these for an experiment in which I condense droplets on a plate made out of/or coated with the material

Just thinking `chemically' I imagine that any polymer with a lot of hydroxyl groups will be hydrophilic (like Polyvinylalcohol), but PVA is water soluble. Polyethylenetereftalate (PET) is reasonable but still has a contact angle around 70 degrees [(common polymer contact angles)](http://www.accudynetest.com/polytable_03.html?sortby=contact_angle)

Does anybody know transparant materials with contact angles closer to 0 that don't dissolve in water? An additional `demand' is that the material does not break easily (like glass)

Comment: Does it have to be a polymer? For example, some very hydrophilic (but insoluble) minerals might have small contact angles: quartz and limestone, for example.

Comment: Not necessarily polymer, but preferably yes. The reason is twofold: the material should not break easily (like glass) and it should be transparant

Comment: If you do not need chemical stability, cellulose esters like nitrocellulose may work. If you find sheet of mica big enough, it may work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several commercially available titanium dioxide coatings are available, commonly used to kill bacteria or aid UV stability (I think). [When exposed to light, the titanium dioxide has a contact angle of almost 0 degrees.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhydrophilicity)

You should be able to deposit a thin layer on something like a PVA or polycarbonate sheet. The commercial coatings are [somewhat expensive](http://www.oxititan.com/store/), though, as far as I can tell, and the common process for doing it yourself involves [heating the surface in a mid-temperature flame for 10-15 minutes](http://www.solideas.com/solrcell/coatglas.html) which excludes pretty much all plastics I know of that would otherwise be suitable.

Comment: Great suggestion! And this could be made transparent by just coating a sufficiently thin layer I guess?

Comment: @michielm: There are at least commercial coatings designed for windows, so I'm assuming so.